# AWS Cloudwatch alarm state not updating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a cloudwatch alarm that is watching a somewhat sparse metrics (manually published at unpredictable intervals).

I didn't think this would be an issue if I used: Treat missing data as "ignore", but it looks like this is not working.

Basically I have a lambda function that is triggered at unpredictable intervals (might not get called for days, or get called 5 times an hour, etc. - it's triggered based on a human-controlled action). 
This lambda function records a metric (ex. # of example metric). If the value is > 0, I want the alarm to go into ALARM. If the value is < 0, I want the alarm to go into OK.

But for some reason, not sure why, the alarm isn't clearing automatically whenever I record a 0 metric from the lambda function. And when I record the metric w/ value of 1, it should go into alarm, but often doesn't.

Am I misunderstanding how these sparce metrics work?

Comment: What is your alarm configuration? It is normally "when the average/sum/count of this metric exceeds a particular value for a period of x minutes". If *x minutes* hasn't passed, then the calculated metric might not change. Feel free to Edit your question to include details of your alarm.